# Full Calendar v5: Filter Out "Busy" Events on Google Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar v5 to display events from 3 Google Calendars and that's working great. For one of the calendars, I want to filter out the events that are marked as Busy on the Google Calendar. Based on what I've read, there is a transparency property that is populated but it's not available in extendedProps. I only see description and location. Is what I'm trying to do not possible? Or is there another way to do it?

Here's a screenshot of the event from the Google Calendar:
[Event in Google Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAPH0.png)

And here's what I see when I do a console log of the event from FullCalendar:
[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VXBy.png)

Here's the code. I'm trying to figure out where the free/busy data is so I can populate var available.

```
    function getEventDetails(event) {
        try {
            console.log(event);
            
            var url = event.url;
            var descr = event.extendedProps.description;
            var loc = event.extendedProps.location;
            //var available = ??????
            
            //var details = "URL: " + url + " Description: " + descr + " Location: " + loc + " Free/Busy: " + available;
            var details = "URL: " + url + " Description: " + descr + "Location: " + loc;
            
            return details;
        }catch(err) {
            console.log("Error: " + err);
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var Fcalendar = document.getElementById('full_calendar');
        
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(Fcalendar, {
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            eventDisplay: 'block',
            
            // Everything that follows is the same as V3
            googleCalendarApiKey: getGoogleAPIKey(),
            eventTextColor: '#FFFFFF',
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prevYear prev',
                center: 'title today',
                right: 'next nextYear'
            },
            
            eventClick: function(info) {
                var details = getEventDetails(info.event);
                
                //prevents browser to visit the event’s url (in the same window/tab)
                info.jsEvent.preventDefault(); 
                
                //JQuery dialog
                $('#dialog').dialog(
                    {
                        autoOpen: false,
                        dialogClass: 'eventDialog',
                        modal: true,
                        closeOnEscape: true,
                        draggable: false,
                        title: info.event.title,
                        width: getDialogWidth(),
                        classes : {
                            "ui-dialog-titlebar": "ui-corner-all " + getEventClass(info.event)
                        }
                    }
                );
                
                $('#dialogContent').html(details);
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                return false;
            },
            eventSources: [
                {
                    id: getFestivalCalendar().id,
                    googleCalendarId: getFestivalCalendar().googleid,
                    editable: false,
                    color: getFestivalCalendar().color
                }, {
                    id: getExhibitCalendar().id,
                    googleCalendarId: getExhibitCalendar().googleid,
                    editable: false,
                    color: getExhibitCalendar().color
                }, {
                    id: getStudioCalendar().id,
                    googleCalendarId: getStudioCalendar().googleid,
                    editable: false,
                    color: getStudioCalendar().color
                }
            ]
        });
        
        calendar.render();
        
    });
```

Comment: Can you show us your code and also an example of what the event fullCalendar creates from the Google event contains in terms of properties/values. It would be good to have a clear example as well as just a description of the issue. Thanks

Comment: I added some screenshots to the original post. I have code to get the description and location and that works fine. It's simple code:
var descr = event.extendedProps.description;
var loc = event.extendedProps.location;

I'd like to do something similar for Free/Busy but can't find it anywhere. It's definitely available because I using the Google Calendar API in another part of my website to get it. I just can't find it through FullCalendar.

Comment: Are you using fullCalendar's ready-made plugin for downloading from Google calendar? As I said, it would help if you could show your code. (And for future reference, as per [ask] please show all code and data as _text_, not screenshots.) Thanks. If you're using the ready-made plugin then you would need to modify that code to get it to take more fields from the google-supplied data (assuming it's available in the feed from Google, but I would guess it is).

Comment: Yes, I'm using the plug-in. My problem is I can't find what I want in the google-supplied data. I was expecting it to be in extendedProps like some of the other data I needed (description, location) but I don't see it. I've updated the original post with some code.

Comment: Like I said, if you're using the ready-made plugin then you would need to modify that code to get it to take more fields from the google-supplied data (assuming it's available in the feed from Google, but I would guess it is). It will be taking only a subset of the Google data to put into the extendedProps. You'd need to modify it so it puts more data in - specifically, the data you want. You'd need to examine the data originally downloaded from Google to see how it's structured, so you know what to look for. I would expect it's visible in the browser network tool if you look

Comment: Then this may not happen. I barely know what I'm doing and am lucky to have gotten this far. :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you look in the un-minified source code, the relevant function you'd need to modify is called "gcalItemToRawEventDef" - see https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.0/main.js

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful. However I think I'm going to hold off because then it becomes a little more work to upgrade the library which I try to stay current on. I did submit a Feature Request for it so maybe it's something that will get added since it sounds like it's a very small change.

Comment: Good idea, if you're happy to be patient then that's probably a better approach.